# Error: Cannot resolve symbol xxxx. Control not generating in the designer.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I've done this a few times now.  I create a telerik control in my aspx or ascx page.

ReSharper and VS show the ID as red with the error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'CartEditPopUp'.

Here is code that generates this error:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="CartEditPopUp" runat="server" 
                   ShowContentDuringLoad="false" Modal="True" 
                   Title="Edit Shopping Cart" 
                   NavigateUrl="ShoppingCartEdit.aspx"
                   Height="520px" Width="680px" 
                   Left="150px"OpenerElementID="showDialog"
                   OnClientClose="CartEditPopUpClose" 
                   OnClientShow="clientShow" 
                   ReloadOnShow="true" 
                   Animation="Resize" EnableShadow="True" 
                   BorderStyle="None" KeepInScreenBounds="True" />
```

How to I get the object to be automatically created in the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error is that it is just a missing space.

Notice this line:

```
Left="150px"OpenerElementID="showDialog"
```

There is no space between `"150px"` and `OpenerElementID`

```
Left="150px" OpenerElementID="showDialog"
```

Corrected this error and the object is automatically created in the designer when the file is saved.